# Prim's Algorithm: How to get index of key on which DECREASE_KEY operation is to be performed?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, prims-algorithm

So I am following this algorithm for Prim's MST

input: graph G(V,E) in the form of adjacency list

1. Create a min heap for vertices using build heap time complexity: O(V)
2. Repeat following steps until no more elements in heap.
3. Call extract-min on heap to get vertex with minimum cost O(log V)
4. For vertex extracted find the adjacent vertices in adjacency list.
5. Perform decrease key operation on adjacent vertices in the heap. O(logn V)

The time complexity analysis for the algorithm given in my class goes something like this:

```
O(V) => to build heap
O(VlogV) => V times EXTRACT_MIN operation
2E => traverse all edges in adjacency list
ElogV => E times DECREASE_KEY operation (Worst Case)

EXTRACT_MIN => O(logV)
DECREASE_KEY => O(logV)

Total Time Complexity = V + V*logV + 2E + E*log V
                      = O((V+E) logV)
```

**My question is before performing decease key operation won't I need to find the corresponding element in the min heap? And searching the element in the heap would take O(V) time.**

[image: Example:]

For the above graph I would do something like this (min heap implemented using array)

```
                      A    B    C    D   E   F
                    ----------------------------------
 chosen as min        0   INF  INF  INF INF INF  ------> cost associated with vertices
                    ------------------------------
 A                        7    2    6   INF INF
                     ------------------------------
 C                        6         6    8   5
                     ------------------------------
 F                        6         3    7
                     ------------------------------
 D                        6              7
                     ------------------------------
 B                                       4
                     ------------------------------
 E
```

My array (min heap) would initially look like this :
Each element consists of two things: the vertex name, the cost.
The min heap is based on cost.

```
 A,0 | B,INF | C,INF | D,INF | E,INF | F,INF
```

Now after getting first minimum element (A) I look for its adjacent vertices in adjacency list 
and find B, C and D. Now I need to perform decrease key operation for these vertices in the min heap.

The DECREASE_KEY operation would work only if I know the index of the vertex on which decrease key operation is to be performed. 
To get the index won't I need to first search for it in the array taking O(V) additional time?

Comment: You can store and update these indices

Comment: @DAle How? You mean separately store these somewhere? Won't I then need to search for those indices?

Comment: Yes, separately store them in array/hashmap (depending on your graph representation) with `O(1)` search operation. And update them on every heap operation/swap.

Comment: If you're working in a language like c# you can make use of pointers, so that the vertices in the adjacency lists of a vertex points to the vertices within the heap, meaning that whenever you update a vertex through the adjancency, the value in the heap will also be updated (actually only the memory is updated once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can* solve this problem the way you want.  It requires keeping pointers back from each vertex to its index in the heap.  Whenever elements in the heap are swapped, the pointers on the two associated vertexes are adjusted.  Then when you need to adjust the key for a vertex you can follow the pointer back to its index in the heap.

However, I usually don't do it that way...

I usually put (cost,vertex) records in the heap, and whenever the cost for a vertex goes down, I just put in a new one.  When I pop a vertex out of the heap, then, I just ignore it if it's already done.  You have to keep track of which vertexes are done anyway, so that is easy.

This takes O(|E|) space instead of O(|V|), but that's usually not a big deal, and the time complexity stays the same.

Comment: Time complexity will not be the same. It will be `O(E*log(E))`

Comment: @DAle, The alternative implementation in this case does not use a Fibonacci heap, it uses a heap array, which makes Dijkstra's algorithm take O(E log V), and since E<V^2, O(E log V) = O(E log E)