# implementing priority queues and heaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap, priority-queue, clrs

I am trying to implement a min priority queue using a binary min heap based on the description from "Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition" and have a couple of questions.

The book says that we often need to store a handle (pointer or integer) to the application object in each heap element and that we also need to store a handle (array index) to the heap element in each application object.

**1)** Would the heap implementation typically look something like this then?

```
template <class KeyType, class ObjectType>
struct HeapElement
{
    KeyType key;
    ObjectType* pObject;
};


template <class KeyType, class ObjectType>
class MinHeap
{
  // ...
private:
  std::vector< HeapElement<KeyType, ObjectType> > data;
};
```

And then the ObjectType class would also store the heapIndex:

```
class Foo
{
 // ...
  int heapIndex;
};
```

**2)** Is the min priority queue and binary min heap typically implemented as a single class or is the min priority queue usually implemented as its own class with a private heap class member?

```
class MinPriorityQueue
{
  // ...
private:
  MinHeap minHeap;
};
```

The reason I ask is because if you look at the implementation for something like `ExtractMin()`, it requires that you manipulate the heap data:

```
int min = data[0]; // data: private heap data member
heapSize--; // heapSize: private heap data member
MinHeapify(0); // MinHeapify: private heap member function
```

So maybe the min priority queue class should act as a wrapper class?

```
T MinPriorityQueue::ExtractMin()
{
  return minHeap.ExtractMin();
}
```

In that case, the binary min heap class might implement `Min()`, `ExtractMin()`, `DecreaseKey()`, and `Insert()` and contain the functionality for both a binary min heap and min priority queue. Then there would be no need for a MinPriorityQueue class at all.

The scope of the question is implementing heaps/priority queues for job interviews. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `std::priority_queue<T>` quite happily implements a priority queue on top of a flat `vector<T>`, with no pointers anywhere. I don't know what CLRS is, but either you misunderstand what it says, or it makes things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Sorry, by CLRS I meant "Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition". The std::priority_queue<T> doesn't support modifying keys once inserted (as far as I know) so how would you make it work for something like Dijkstra's algorithm? I am also asking for interview purposes, though, in case I have to implement it myself.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't require modifying keys once inserted. `std::priority_queue` comes with source code, you can study how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Usually you don't want to have to modify your value types just because you want to make a heap of them.  You'd make your heap something like this:

```
template <class KeyType, class ObjectType>
struct HeapElement
{
    KeyType key;
    size_t heapIndex;
    ObjectType* pObject;
};


template <class KeyType, class ObjectType>
class MinHeap
{
  // ...
private:
  //this is just to allocate the data.  Elements in here don't move
  std::vector< HeapElement<KeyType, ObjectType> > data;

  //this is the heap.  Elements are indexes into data vector
  std::vector<size_t> heapArray;
};
```

Then, throughout the implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm you use indexes into the data vector to refer to objects, and you can get each item's heap index with `data[itemIndex].heapIndex`.

BUT see my answer over here:  [Prim's Algorithm: How to get index of key on which DECREASE_KEY operation is to be performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004917/prims-algorithm-how-to-get-index-of-key-on-which-decrease-key-operation-is-to/48017333#48017333) ...  I usually implement Dijkstra's algorithm *without* a decrease_key operation.

2) I don't really see any reason to make a heap class that is separate from the priority queue implementation.  I would actually call the class you need a "Heap", though, not a priority queue, since priority queue interfaces don't usually expect the keys to be separate from the objects.

You *should* use `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap` on a vector.