# Modifying an item in a PriorityQueue in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Say I have a custom class as below

```
class Emp {
   String name;
   Integer id;
}
```

I decide to use a PriorityQueue in java to insert the elements of Emp and provide a custom comparator on `id` field of the class. Say `max-heap`.

I understand `pop` and `offer` will keep the heap property intact. Now my question is, if I want to modify the value of `id` for an instance of `Emp`, how do I do it? Even if I maintain a HashMap to find the object that I want to modify readily, even if I do, it will destroy the heap property. Isn't it?

What is the best way to achieve this? I also cannot delete the element from heap at random and re-insert?

Shall I just use a `TreeMap`?

Comment: You would have to remove the instance from the PriorityQueue, modify it, and add it again. Using a TreeMap would not help. The same problem applies, and it would require the same solution. These data structures do not expect the data they contain to change on-the-fly.

Comment: You can delete the element from the heap, with [`remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), but the time complexity is linear, O(n). So, not great.

Comment: If I use a TreeMap, it might be better than heap I believe because deletion in treemap is faster then finding a node in PQ and deleting it I think

Comment: That is probably true, yes. Finding the item to delete in a TreeMap would be faster.

Comment: Could you try IndexedPriorityQueue? This will allow to efficiently update the priority of an element without removing it completely. Other elements will not be disturbed and heap property will be maintained as well.

Comment: @AbdulAlimShakir I don't think the JDK contains a (public/API) class named `IndexedPriorityQueue`. Is that from a library?

Comment: You can build it from scratch :  [IndexedPriorityQueue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexed-priority-queue-with-implementation) or use [IndexMinPQ of Princeton University](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004917/prims-algorithm-how-to-get-index-of-key-on-which-decrease-key-operation-is-to/48017333#48017333